# Target only posts in custom wordpress template

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

The following code crashes my site. I am trying to target ONLY posts. Not sure why.

Also my php opening and closing is fine but i couldn't get it to appear here otherwise

```php
<?php if(is_single('post')); ?>

    <header>
        test 
    </header>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to say `post` in `is_single()`

Try this - it should check if it's single and it's a 'post'

```
< ?php if( is_single() && 'post' === get_post_type() ); ? >

< header >
    test 
</ header >
< ?php endif; ? >
```

Comment: Didn't work but with some more fenageling I WAS able to get this to work:
<?php  if(is_single() && get_post_type() == 'post' ) {
print("testing"); 
}
 ?>